# How to add numbers in a text file together with PHP?

Tags: php, addition

I currently have a text file that looks like this:

```
Test1 = 120827 = December 23, 2012:
Test2 = 147203 = December 23, 2012:
Test3 = 11806 = December 23, 2012:
Test4 = 11806 = December 23, 2012:
Test5 = 0 = December 23, 2012:
```

What I want to do, is add all of the numbers in the second column all together. How can I do this with PHP? My actual file is much bigger than this one.

```
Test1 = *120827 = December 23, 2012:
Test2 = *147203 = December 23, 2012:
Test3 = *11806 = December 23, 2012:
Test4 = *11806 = December 23, 2012:
Test5 = *0 = December 23, 2012:
```

*What I want to add.

Any help would be highly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried?  Is PHP your only option?  This would be pretty simple to do with bash/core utils

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$pattern = '/(?<=\=\s)([0-9]+)(?=\s\=)/';
$total = 0;
$matches;
$filename = "add.txt";
$handle = @fopen($filename, "r");

if ($handle) {
    while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {        
        if(preg_match($pattern, $buffer, $matches))
        {
            $total += intval($matches[0]);  
        }       
    }
    if (!feof($handle)) {
        echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP:

```
$sum = 0;
foreach (file($filename) as $line) {
   list(,,$num) = explode(' ', $line);
   $sum += $num;
}
```

If the file is too large, use `fopen`+`fgets` instead of `file`.

BASH:

```
cut -d' ' -f3 filename | paste -sd+ | bc
```

Comment: It did not work, it just showed a lot of zeros. Would I just echo $sum?